# Ethereum: How to use ERC20 token in python project?

Tags: erc-20, etherscan, python, populus

I'm gonna develop python project for ehtereum using populus framework.
In my project, I also planed to use ERC20 token.
In fact, I didn't select any library and framework for my project.
Can anyone tell me which framework and library I need to select and how to use ERC20 token?
Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are well versed in Python you can use `token.py` library:

- https://github.com/carver/ethtoken.py

Otherwise I suggest you start learning Ethereum and Solidity with Populus project:

- http://populus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/